# JfreeChart method, setBaseToolTipGenerator cannot be found in org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYBarRenderer

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, jfreechart

```
    // Create volume chart renderer
    XYBarRenderer timeRenderer = new XYBarRenderer();
    timeRenderer.setShadowVisible(false);
    timeRenderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardXYToolTipGenerator("Volume--> Time={1} Size={2}", new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm"), new DecimalFormat("0")));
```

Hi all,

I got the following error message while compliling the code above:

```
com/fx/jfree/chart/candlestick/JfreeCandlestickChart.java:[101,29] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method setBaseToolTipGenerator(org.jfree.chart.labels.StandardXYToolTipGenerator)
  location: variable timeRenderer of type org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYBarRenderer
1 error
```

Thanks in advance for your help,

Space.

Answer (score 1):

See [*Migration from JFreeChart 1.0.x*](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart#migration-from-jfreechart-10x), which suggests,

> many methods `getBaseXXX()/setBaseXXX()` have been renamed `setDefaultXXX()/getDefaultXXX()`;

Instead, try this:

```
timeRenderer.setDefaultToolTipGenerator(…);
```